# How can I get redirect URL using function based view?

Tags: python, django, django-views

I have 2 views, `display_quote` and `quoteline_update`

After updating a `quoteline`, I want to redirect to `display_quote` (quote to which the `quoteline` updated belongs).
I obtain the error:

```
Reverse for 'display_quote' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['\\^display_quote/\\(\\?P(?P<pk>[^/]+)\\\\d\\+\\)\\$$']
Exception Type:NoReverseMatch
```

Views:

```
def display_quote(request, pk):
    items_quote = Quote.objects.filter(pk=pk)
    items_quote_line = LineQuote.objects.all().filter(num_quote_id=pk)

    form = QuoteLineForm(request.POST or None)
       if request.method == "POST":
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
    total = 0
    for item in items_quote_line:
        total = total + item.get_price()

    context = {'items_quote': items_quote,
               'items_quote_line': items_quote_line,
               'form': form,
               'total':total
              }

    return render(request, 'quote/quote_display.html', context)


    def quoteline_update(request, pk):
    model = QuoteLine
    cls = LigneDevisForm
    item = get_object_or_404(model, id=pk)

    if request.method == "POST":
        form = cls(request.POST, instance=item)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('display_quote')
    else:
        form = cls(instance=item)

        return render(request, 'quote/quoteline_update.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: Add your `urls.py` code. Do you want to see the detail of the updated quote or go to the list of all of them. You are missing the id if you want to go to the detail url.

Comment: You need to provide `pk` to reverse the `display_quote` URL, e.g `return redirect('display_quote', pk=pk)`

Comment: Thanks you gdef and Alasdair.
@Alasdair, it works! I just changed pk = pk by pk =item.num_quote_id